# Are there disadvantages from deriving AbstractBaseClasses (ABCs) from noncopyable?

Tags: c++, boost

These recommendations [boost::pointer_container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/guidelines.html#derive-your-base-class-from-boost-noncopyable)  suggest that one derives ABCs from boost::noncopyable to prevent slicing further down the hierarchy. Apart from the mentioned advantages, are there reasons why I should not follow this recommendation?

Comment: @Frank. I've changed the title

Comment: Abstract base classes are inherently non-copyable. The recommendation you link to refers specifically to non-abstract base classes.

Comment: @Frank, this is not the impression that I get from the article. The idea that I get is that we make our ABC non-copyable to prevent copying further down the hierarchy (because making base non-copyable implies derived is by default)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a thing called "empty base optimization" that will prevent derived class from growing when deriving from base class that has no non-static data members and no virtual functions (that is no vtable). MS Visual C++ however implements such optimization only for first base class (that is minimal standard requirement if I remember correctly). So if you want to derive your class from two empty base classes you'll waste empy base optimization on the `::boost::noncopyable`. So it would be better to explicitly write deleted constructors / assignment operators in this case.

Comment: ... explicitly write delete constructors/assignment operators in the leaf classes, I take it? Useful info...

Comment: Not at all. I regret you reading it that way. I really did not know EBCO is removed, or it did not occur to me